# Variable not returning actual values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want correctly return some variables (arrays)

```
kazkas.Ads[n]; (n = how many ads are)
kazkas.Ads[n].id;
kazkas.Ads[n].Days[m].Stats.Clicks;  // every day have his own clicks
kazkas.Ads[n].Days[m].Stats.Impresons; // every day have his own impresions
```

from this method and use these variables in other class.

```
 public static void GetAdsStats(string Ticket, DateTime start, DateTime end, int CamId)
    {
        var client = new CampaignStatsServiceClient();
        var id = new CampaignIdFilter();
        id.CampaignId = CamId;
        var statsdata = new GetAdStatsData();
        var kazkas = new Campaign();


        kazkas = client.GetAdStats(Ticket, new GetAdStatsData
        {
            IdFilter = id,
            StartDate = start,
            EndDate = end
        });
        long AllClicks = 0;
        long AllImpresions = 0;
        int reklamos = kazkas.Ads.Length;
        long[] statistikaClikai = new long[reklamos];
        long[] statistikaImpresions = new long[reklamos];
        for (int i = 0; i < reklamos; i++)
        {
            int dienos = kazkas.Ads[i].Days.Length;
            for (int lop = 0; lop < dienos; lop++)
            {

                AllClicks = AllClicks + kazkas.Ads[i].Days[lop].Stats.Clicks;
                AllImpresions = AllImpresions + kazkas.Ads[i].Days[lop].Stats.Impressions;

            }
            statistikaClikai[i] = AllClicks;
            statistikaImpresions[i] = AllImpresions;

        }

    }
```

I know that void type can't return anything, but this how I know that my method works ( from debugging). Like you see I was trying do that with for loop. Here i have 9 Ads and every ad have one day.

Like I says I want return every Ads id[in array], and every days.stats.impresions and days.stats.click

how can I do that ? Ore how return more variables/arrays from method to other class, I am using webservises, so i cant use database ore something like that.

Comment: can you show example, because the return is the hardest thing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen by the downvotes of the question, you need to **design** the return value and then code against it.

Your query almost does it (now):

```
kazkas.Ads[n]; (n = how many ads are)
kazkas.Ads[n].id;
kazkas.Ads[n].Days[m].Stats.Clicks;  // every day have his own clicks
kazkas.Ads[n].Days[m].Stats.Impressions; // every day have his own impressions
```

Your existing code show this should be expanded to include:

```
kazkas.Ads[n].Total.Clicks;
kazkas.Ads[n].Total.Impressions;
```

So now you're ready to design. First you want a Stat Class that just contains CLicks and Impressions:

```
public class Stat
{
   public long Impressions { get; set; }
   public long Clicks { get; set; }
}
```

An optimisation here may be to use a struct, but I won't go into that.

As you currently have defined it each Day has just a Stats property:

```
public class DayStat
{
   public Stat Stats { get; set; }
}
```

Now finally we can define the top level AdStat:

```
public class AdStat
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public DayStat Day[];
   public Stat Total { get; set; }
}
```

Etc... There's further issues here, such as ensuring arrays are created and `Stat` instances are never `null` (which is why making some of these classes structs is an option). But I'm really a VB programmer so I'll stop here before I get caught typing crap into the SO IDE :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class or struct with members you need

```
public class Stat
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public long Clicks { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Change the signature of your method from `void GetAdsStats` to `IEnumberable<Stat> GetAdsStats` and either return a collection of stats or use `yield` keyword to return the stat object.

Also if you do not want your method to return anything (return type `void`) do not use a name starting with `Get`.

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Stat> GetAdsStats(...)
{
   ...
   var statList = new List<Stat>();
   for (int i = 0; i < reklamos; i++)
   {
        var stat = new Stat();
        statList.Add(stat);
        int dienos = kazkas.Ads[i].Days.Length;
        for (int lop = 0; lop < dienos; lop++)
        {

            AllClicks = AllClicks + kazkas.Ads[i].Days[lop].Stats.Clicks;
            AllImpresions = AllImpresions + kazkas.Ads[i].Days[lop].Stats.Impressions;

        }
        stat.Clicks = AllClicks;
        stat.Impression = AllImpresions;

    }

    return statList;
}
```

Comment: Why not? This is a POCO object, it does not have any logic, it can be serialized/deserialized, etc.

Comment: Can you show write a little example how return should looks like, or how put variables/arrays in <Stat>

Answer (score 0):

Change your `void` to the type you want to return, say `Campaign`, and return the appropriate variable. The variables you define in your method, only live in your method and are not accessible from another method or class.

Comment: No, because I do not know what you want to return. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: i want to return 
kazkas.Ads[n]; (n = how many ads are)
kazkas.Ads[n].id;
kazkas.Ads[n].Days[m].Stats.Clicks;  // every day have his own clicks
kazkas.Ads[n].Days[m].Stats.Impresons; // every day have his own impresions